# Best way to use RandomAccessFile is Java

Tags: java, performance, large-data, randomaccessfile

I am creating a utility which write MSSQL table blob to data disk file using RandomAccessFile. It is too slower because we need to seek the last position always and write the stream contents.. please let me know any other alternative to speedup the randomaccessfile writing.

I have more than 50M records, with current logic it took approx 10 hours.

my code block is something like that:

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
InputStream inputStream = null;

while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.next();
    inputStream = (InputStream) row.getValues()[0];
    offset = randomAccessFile.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
    int count;
    randomAccessFile.seek(offset);
    randomAccessFile.setLength(offset);
    while ((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        randomAccessFile.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
}
randomAccessFile.close();
```

Comment: Do you need to write in a file from a specific location? Just wanted to understand why you selected RandomAccessFile. you could have used BufferedWriter as well.

Comment: Writing 50 MB of data should take a second. You can test thus by just writing blank data of this size. If it more than this, it's the time to extract the data from the database.

Comment: Btw setLength is exceedingly slow in Java 9 and 10. This is fine in Java 8 and 11.

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you posted, you only need to append to an existing file. This is done easier and more efficient using a buffered writer in append mode.

Thus, use

```
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOptions.CREATE, StandardOpenOptions.APPEND);
```

instead.

Update after Peter's comment: for an output stream, the whole thing is basically the same, only that `Files` does not have a nice convenience function for the "buffered" part. Therfore:

```
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND));
```

Comment: Writers are for writing text. The OP probably wants a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: We would need to write binary data too, we don't know what are the data in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are writing roughly 8 Kb (8196 / 1024) of data in each iteration and each iteration does an I/O operation which is blocking and takes time. Try to increase this to at least 1 Mb roughly (10,000,000).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000000];
```

Comment: Buffers larger than 32KB can be slower as they don't fit in the L1 data cache.

Comment: yes..I have row which contents 1KB data, so I think current size is okay.